# ValueError in jupyter notebook, keras, tensorflow for neural nets

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

I need help with Keras Neural Net

I have no education in programming. I want to make Neural Network to classify data (few target categorical variables and around 88 predictors). I made this by fixing errors and constant googleing:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras import layers

import keras.models

from keras import backend as K

from keras.layers import Activation, Dense

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/quad/Desktop/obradjeni podaci/Obradjeni podaci za TF.xlsx')

df.head(2720)

data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/quad/Desktop/obradjeni podaci/Obradjeni podaci za TF.xlsx')

train_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/quad/Desktop/obradjeni podaci/Obradjeni podaci za TF.xlsx')

train_df = pd.read_excel( 'C:/Users/quad/Desktop/obradjeni podaci/Obradjeni podaci za TF.xlsx' )

test_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/quad/Desktop/obradjeni podaci/Obradjeni podaci za TF.xlsx')

train_X = train_df.drop(columns=['Dalikonzumiratecigare'])

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_y = to_categorical(train_df.Dalikonzumiratecigare)

from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

n_cols = train_X.shape[1]

model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))

model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),

loss='categorical_crossentropy',

metrics=['accuracy'])

train_labels = train_data.pop('Dalikonzumiratecigare')

test_labels = test_data.pop('Dalikonzumiratecigare')

train_data = data.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)

test_data = data.drop(train_data.index)


train_X = train_X.transpose(92)

test_X = test_X.transpose(92)
```

It seems that I can't google this problem away: Output: ValueError: the 'axes' parameter is not supported in the pandas implementation of transpose()

Please help me. I am desperate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`train_X` and `train_Y` are pandas `DataFrame` object and not numpy `ndarray` object. The **transpose method is called on a `ndarray` object. You are calling it on the `DataFrame` object and hence the error.** To get a `ndarray` out of a pandas `DataFrame` use :

```
X = train_X.values
Y = train_Y.values
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it!